# Bitwise operating issue

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to rebuild a function for generating GUIDs used by the game Arma 3 in a MySQL function. There are some examples in various languages over here: https://gist.github.com/Fank/11127158

Basicially this is what I tried so far:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `generateGUID`(playerid varchar(17)) RETURNS varchar(32) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
 DECLARE temp bigint;
 DECLARE i int;

 SET i = 0;
 SET temp = 0;

 WHILE i < 8 DO
    SET temp = temp + CHAR(playerid & 0xFF);
    SET playerid = playerid >> 8;
    SET i = i + 1;
 END WHILE;

RETURN MD5("BE" + temp);
END
```

What I understood so far orientating at the php example:

First of all we have the steamid given as a varchar.

Afterwards we are iterating 8 times and adding the char of the bitwise addition of the playerid and the value of 0xFF. Then we are performing a 8 bitwise right shift on the playerid.

Afterwards the string "BE" is added the temp result and a md5 is generated of this and returned.

However I'm facing the issue that this function always returns 0. I tried many things so far, like using a blob instead of an int for the temp var.

**Edit:** After the hint to use `CONCAT` instead of the `+` operator the result is still not matching with the guid calculators out there.

The code looks now like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `generateGUID`(playerid varchar(17)) RETURNS varchar(32) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
 DECLARE temp bigint;
 DECLARE i int;

 SET i = 0;
 SET temp = "";

 WHILE i < 8 DO
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp, CHAR(playerid & 0xFF));
    SET playerid = playerid >> 8;
    SET i = i + 1;
 END WHILE;

RETURN MD5(CONCAT("BE", temp));
END
```

However, using the playerid `76561197996545192` the function returns `2a0f7ebed67e04afaf7ea032e1ed22e3` instead of `cd97cc68c1038b485b081ba2aa3ea6fa` which should be the expected output.

Comment: Use CONCAT() function for string concatinations - not `+`.

Comment: Thanks  @PaulSpiegel. I edited my original post, there is still one issue I'm facing

Comment: Try to debug it and find out where the first difference occures comparing it to the PHP solution.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the CHAR() function.

Comment: I added it back but the result still doesn't matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `generateGUID`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `generateGUID`(`playerid` BIGINT UNSIGNED) RETURNS varchar(32) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE temp text CHARSET ascii;
 DECLARE i int;

 SET i = 0;
 SET temp = "";

 WHILE i < 8 DO
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp, CHAR(playerid & 0xFF));
    SET playerid = playerid >> 8;
    SET i = i + 1;
 END WHILE;

RETURN MD5(CONCAT("BE", temp));
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cc709/1